# What word describes the use of letter casing to stylize a brand name?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, a company might use any of:

- thecompany
- Thecompany
- TheCompany
- THeCompany

.. to refer to themselves. I remember learning at one point that there's a term to describe the stylized representation of a word in this way. I believe the word would be used in one of the following ways:

- Their preferred __ is TheCompany
- Marketing listed several options for the ___

It's not any of:

- trademark
- branding
- logo
- typography
- camelCase
- snake_case
- PascalCase

Comment: Would it be *branding*?

Comment: No, it wasn't branding. It was more specific to the text representation

Comment: You might be looking for *logo*.

Comment: It definitely wasn't a common word like those. I believe it ended in "ation" and had appeared on one of those "10 words for things you didn't know had a name" lists

Comment: Stylization? There are lots of questions about similar things here, if you search for capitalization and branding/trademark you might find some term that matches what you want.

Comment: "capitalization" refers to the way you use capital letters in a word.

Comment: Is *fuglyphication* a word yet? :) Or maybe given ᴛʜᴇmatTeraThand™, that’s supposed to be *fuGlyphication*. Or *fuglyphiCation*. Or *FuglyPhication*.  We have endLess possibilities here.

Comment: there's Magusculation, but It's a bit Different.

Comment: Informally this is just called 'orthography' (how you write something out) or 'spelling' (how you spell something). For example, the word iPhone is spelled with a small I. "IPhone" with a capital I is considered to be an incorrect spelling.

Comment: A Google search for  << non-standard orthgography  >> yields a claimed 2+ million results.

Answer (score 3):

Wordmark (or word mark): n. A logotype; a standardized graphic representation of the name of a company or product used for purposes of easy identification. It is is often text with unique typographic treatments. Usually the company name is incorporated together with simple graphic treatments, so that the representation of the word essentially becomes a symbol of the company.

Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordmark

Example: [image]

~OR~

Logotype: n. a single piece of type that prints a word or group of separate letters.

https://99designs.com/blog/logo-branding/logotype-vs-logomark-vs-logo/

Answer (score 2):

There is

> **CamelCase.** The style of writing by concatenating multiple component words, (i.e., writing without any space between them), while capitalizing the first letter of each word, starting with the first or the second word.

So, in the OP examples, this would be only `TheCompany`.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a more generic word. CamelCase as used in computing is one particular convention when writing words together with no spaces, but it's not the only possible convention.

Comment: The OP says it is not camelCase.

Comment: @Stucco Yes, but the suggestion was CamelCase, not the ruled-out camelCase. Because, see, it's not like camelCase and CamelCase have *anything* to do with each other. They're completely different things, like apples and Apples. :)